# CSS Font Shorthand Validation

Tags: css, validation, w3c-validation

I put some css through the w3 validator (I know it's kind of pointless since it balks at css3) but I found a couple things that I was trying to fix that could have been wrong.

This was one of the errors that it found, but I don't see anything wrong with it.  Maybe you guys can see something I don't.

The error that it's giving is...

> Value Error : font / is not a font-family value : bold 3.7em / 0.82 Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif

The code is...

```
font:bold 3.7em/0.82 Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
```

JJ

Comment: It's true in the past by default the validator checked against CSS 2 and spat out errors for CSS 3 unless you explicitly asked it to check against 3, but no longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I <s>think</s> am fairly sure this must be a bug in the validator ([you're not the only one with the problem](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&output=search&q=font+shorthand+validation+w3c)) since I pulled one of the examples off from the [official specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand) on this, and it got the same error.

I validated this:

```
* { font: bold 3.7em/0.82 Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif; }
p { font: x-large/110% "New Century Schoolbook", serif } /* from specs */
```

And got this:

```
Sorry! We found the following errors (2)
URI : TextArea
1    *   Value Error : font / is not a font-family value : bold 3.7em / 0.82,Impact,Charcoal,sans-serif
2    p   Value Error : font / is not a font-family value : x-large / 110% "New Century Schoolbook",serif
```

Sources:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-shorthand
- http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

The jigsaw css validator is not perfect. It's software, so it contains bugs. Best thing to do in these cases is to inspect the specifications on the subject and try to validate sample code and if it does validate in that case, try and see how it is different from your own.

Comment: I feel kind of dumb for not googling it.  I just assumed that I messed something up.  You guys are so smart.

Answer (score 2):

[The bug was reported](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator-css/2012May/0003.html) May 3, 2012, in the W3C CSS Validator’s mailing list. No response yet, and I would expect it to take several days, maybe weeks, before the bug gets fixed. It is probably related to their rewriting some parts of processing property values related to fonts, in which process some other bugs have arisen too (now fixed).

Either wait for the developments and check this kind of parts of your CSS code manually, or use individual font properties instead of the `font` shorthand. CSS shorthands are generally risky, not due to browser bugs (any more) but due to conceptual difficulties and people’s tendency of making mistakes with such constructs with complicated semantics and syntactic specialties.

It is hardly useful to rewrite bulks of existing code for such reasons, but for individual rules and for new code, it is probably better to avoid ´font:bold 3.7em/0.82 Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;´(even though it is conforming) and use individual properties instead:

```
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 3.7em;
line-height: 0.82;
font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
```

The main reason why people use `font` shorthands is probably that they use the *same* settings in many places, in several rules. It is generally possible, and better for maintainability and code readability, to write the settings once and use a suitable list of selectors in the rule, covering just the elements needed.

Comment: This bug in the W3C CSS Validator has now been fixed. If you still observe it, please report via a mailing list as described at http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/Email.html